# How do I get a value from a json file that is identified by a number

Tags: javascript, json

So imagine this
Theres a json file built like this

```
{
    "data": [
    
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "name1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "name2"
        }
    ]
}
```

How would I go about grabbing the related value "name" from the json file if I knew the ID to it.

I know this might seem like a dumb question, but I'm new to JS and I hope to learn from this x.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const data = {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "name1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "name2"
        }
    ]
}

const id = '1'

const name = data.data.find(obj => obj.id === id).name

console.log(name)
```

Comment: 10 year duplicate

Comment: So for sure outdated ;)

Comment: top answer with nearly 2000 votes: `myArray.find(x => x.id === '45').foo;` with a complete description of alternatives and excerpts from the documentation